# How do I set the "crop" (not aspect ratio) to 16:9?

Tags: vlc-media-player, crop

Is it possible to set the default crop to 16:9 so I don't have to do it every time a movie starts on VLC playlist? Default aspect ratio 16:9 stretches the video to much to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, add 16:9 to Video Cropping as in my screenshot. To get the advanced settings, click "All" at the bottom left corner.

[image]

Comment: I added the ratio to the `Custom crop ratios list`, and had to restart.

Comment: @jezmck: 16:9 is on the VLC's default list of crop aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2):

On vlc's preferences, at the bottom, set `show settings` to `all` and on the list on the left scroll down to `video`.

Under `window settings` (i'm guessing the name, since mine is in another language), there should be a `video crop` setting. Set it to `16:9` and save.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that to set a default crop of 2.35:1, you need to add 235:100 in the box. It doesn't accept it with the dot.
Tools -> Preferences -> Switch to "All" (from "Simple") -> Video -> Video cropping -> 235:100 -> Save

PS: current VLC media player version 3.0.18